# Should UserControls expose arbitrary properties or just a ViewModel?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui-3, c++-winrt, winui

When I'm designing a cool new `UserControl` for WinUI 3 or UWP, should I prefer creating a control with many properties, or a control that binds directly to a ViewModel?

### Example

For argument, let's take this [basic card from Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/#basic-card):

[image: a basic card]

Should I prefer:

#### Approach 1: expose many properties

```xml
<!-- Many properties -->
<Card
    Subtitle="Word of the Day"
    Title="Be*nev*o*lent"
    LowerSubtitle="adjective"
    Description="well meaning and kindly. 'a benevolent smile'"
    LinkText="Learn more"
    LinkUri="http://example.com" />
```

#### Approach 2: expose only ViewModel

```xml
<!-- Bind to ViewModel -->
<Card ViewModel="{x:Bind SomeViewModel}" />
```

```
runtimeclass CardViewModel: Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    CardViewModel();
    String Subtitle{ get; };
    String Title{ get; };
    String LowerSubtitle{ get; };
    String Description{ get; };
    String LinkText{ get; };
    Uri LinkUri{ get; };
}
```

### Background

In the C++/WinRT guide [XAML controls; bind to a C++/WinRT property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property) (the official intro to using [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) with XAML), you end up binding some data directly to a ViewModel:

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<Button Click="ClickHandler" Content="{x:Bind MainViewModel.BookSku.Title, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

It even writes (in the context of comparing ViewModels to Models, emphasis added):

> **A view model is an abstraction of a view, and so it's bound directly to the view (the XAML markup).** A data model is an abstraction of data, and it's consumed only from your view models, and not bound directly to XAML. So you can declare your data models not as runtime classes, but as C++ structs or classes. They don't need to be declared in MIDL, and you're free to use whatever inheritance hierarchy you like.

It's not clear to me if this is saying "ViewModels and View code-behind should be bound to a View, not Models" or "ViewModels should be bound to a view, not View code-behind or Models."

Furthermore, in the follow-up, [XAML custom (templated) controls with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/xaml-cust-ctrl), you create a `BgLabelControl` with DependencyProperties:

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<local:BgLabelControl Background="Red" Label="Hello, World!"/>
```

But it doesn't explain when you'd want to take this approach (versus the MainPage approach) nor what is idiomatic for a `UserControl` (not a `Control`).

It's not clear to me from that documentation:

- Whether I should prefer (Dependency)Properties or direct ViewModel binding, in general?
- Whether this differs between `Control`s, `UserControl`s, and `Page`s?

### Conclusion

Thus:

How do I decide when to expose properties on my `UserControl`s or when to bind them directly to ViewModels?

Comment: *"When I'm designing a cool new `UserControl` for WinUI 3 or UWP, should I prefer creating a control with many properties [...]?"* - Yes, sure! All *cool* controls do (and will [eventually become unusable](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/1287)).

Comment: In general, you create properties on your control, and you make sure these properties are all DependencyProperties, so you can bind them on any object (that usually supports INotifyPropertyChanged and friends to enable automatic change). So it's approach 1 and 2, like `<Card Title="{x:Bind Some.Object.ThatIDontKnowYet.TitleProp}" />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no general clear rules or principles for this but let me answer to your questions.

> Whether I should prefer (Dependency)Properties or direct ViewModel binding, in general?
> Whether this differs between Controls, UserControls, and Pages?

Use `DependencyProperties` for (Custom) `Controls` and `UserControls`, and **ViewModels** for `Pages`.

**Notes**

- If you expose only a **ViewModel** in your controls, it'll be very hard to reuse your controls with other models.
- **ViewModel** is like an adapter that works between your **View** and **Models**. It might have a simple logic but try to make it as simple as possible.
- It's OK to have UI related code like `FilePickerDialogs` or `VisualState` changes in your code-behind.

Comment: This makes sense; but what about controls that are typically bound to a specific ViewModel. Do I need an "adapter control" that x:Binds a specific ViewModel to the generic control?

Comment: I would never, actually, I have never seen a control that exposes a ViewModel. ``Controls`` usually expose ``DependencyProperties`` and **ViewModels** interact with ``Controls`` via binding. Of course, you can expose a class with several properties as a single ``DependencyProperty`` but I wouldn't call it **ViewModel**.

Comment: I asked a follow-up, so this isn't handled in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75815721/how-do-i-consistently-bind-a-viewmodel-to-a-view :)

Comment: @citelao [The Benefit of MVVM is decoupling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm). There is no document to provide a so-called official general approach but [microsoft-ui-xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/8390ab44f93e643434059d45aefb29b2f7070a87/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView.idl#L170) uses DependencyProperties through [MIDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro).